# nmap socket trouble

Tags: linux, nmap

I've been trying to use nmap but it fails with the following output:

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-06-21 22:24 PDT
NSOCK ERROR [0.3460s] nsock_make_socket(): Socket trouble: Address family not supported by protocol
nmap: nsock_core.c:1268: nsp_add_event: Assertion `nse->iod->sd >= 0' failed.
```

I'm trying to do `nmap -O 172.16.1.11` but `nmap scanme.nmap.org` also fails. I'm running a vanilla 4.7.0-rc4 kernel. The nic is an Intel 82583V Gigabit nic. The system is not running in a VM.

Comment: Please add Linux distro, kernel version and virtualisation technology to the question.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro alright I did.

Comment: If it is a VM please add the virtualization technology and/or the type of nic.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro alright.

Comment: It seems to me you are hitting a kernel bug. In the past it happened with VMs.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was an **ipv6 dns** in `/etc/resolv.conf` causing the problem since ipv6 was disabled in the system, after commenting all ipv6 dns's `nmap` functioned properly.

Comment: thanks! had the same issue on Ubuntu 20 and your solution worked

Answer (score 0):

For Nmap crashes, you will generally get better help by writing to the [nmap-dev mailing list](http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/) or [filing a bug report on Github](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/issues/new). Your bug report should include the following:

- Full output of `nmap --version`. Since you're not running the latest version, you should [download it](https://nmap.org/download.html) and see if you still have problems.
- Output of your command with the `-d` option to turn on debugging output.
- A full description of your computer: OS, kernel version, network type, etc.

This particular bug is not one that I have seen before, and we would be very interested in fixing it if it does affect Nmap 7.12 (the latest version as of mid-2016).